# Find an space with a given task between timeslots

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I need:

Print the ID of employees who has availability on a certain span of time, e.g: `from 28-12-2014 10:00 to 28-12-2014 11:00`
These employees might be doing some other activities which are on a BD according to this picture: [Table of ongoing activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV9Lh.png)

What I have:

At the moment I am comparing those dates vs the one that I need, row by row like this:

```
$sql_reservas="SELECT * FROM `Reservas` WHERE `ID_Empleado`= 2";
        $result_reservas = mysqli_query($link,$sql_reservas);    
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result_reservas)>0){        
        foreach($result_reservas as $row_reservas ) {          
        ongoing_start       = new DateTime("{$row_reservas['Inicio']}"); //28-12-2014 11:45 then 28-12-2014 09:45
        ongoing_finish      = new DateTime("{$row_reservas['Libre']}"); //28-12-2014 13:45 then 28-12-2014 10:45
        new_activity_start  = $_POST['date'] //28-12-2014 10:00
        new_activity_finish = $_POST['date2'] //28-12-2014 11:00
        If(new_activity_start<ongoing_start && new_activity_finish<ongoing_start ){
        //I have space before the ongoing activities
        echo $row_reservas['ID_Empleado'];
        }elseif(new_activity_start>ongoing_finish && new_activity_finish>ongoing_finish) {
        //I have space after the ongoing activities
       echo $row_reservas['ID_Empleado'];       
       }else{
        //overlaps with the compared one
        echo "not available";

        }}}
```

The problem:

When there is just one booking (like the ID 3 or 4 or 5...) everything works fine, BUT when there are 2 or more bookings (like with ID 2) it will still let me book the space because one of the two ongoing activities is not overlapping with the requested date

I hope you can help me with this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the order of the loop and the echo

```
available = true;
foreach ($result_reservas as $row_reservas ) {          
    ongoing_start       = new DateTime("{$row_reservas['Inicio']}"); //28-12-2014 11:45 then 28-12-2014 09:45
    ongoing_finish      = new DateTime("{$row_reservas['Libre']}"); //28-12-2014 13:45 then 28-12-2014 10:45
    new_activity_start  = $_POST['date'] //28-12-2014 10:00
    new_activity_finish = $_POST['date2'] //28-12-2014 11:00
    if (new_activity_start<ongoing_start && new_activity_finish<ongoing_start  || 
        new_activity_start>ongoing_finish && new_activity_finish>ongoing_finish) {
    //I have space after the ongoing activities
        $id = $row_reservas['ID_Empleado'];       
    } else {
        available = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (available) {
    echo $id;
} else {
    echo "not available";
}
```

Comment: but this does the same as the one i have doesnt it?

Comment: sorry, didn't see this.
It is not the same, since it looks for all the rows before considering if the worker is available. your code decides for each entry.
Therefore I started the answer with the loop and echo order.